# Retrieving variable from Specific page onload of a web page - Razor web pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2

Currently I am running multiple RenderPages on one page. I want to retrieve a specific variable from another page and return it to the _SiteLayout page on onload of the page.

Page 1:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Home Page";
    Page.Description = @RenderPage("~/Content/testCard.cshtml") , return {description}));
}
<article>
    <p>
       @RenderPage("~/Content/testCard.cshtml", new { renderOption = "card-1" })
    </p>

    <p>
        @RenderPage("~/Content/testCard.cshtml", new { renderOption = "card-1" })
    </p>
</article>
```

I want to retreive the Page.Description from the testCard.cshtml where it is stored and it references back to the _SiteLayout.cshtml as part of my `<head>` information

Comment: How does `testCard.cshtml` gets the desired data?

Comment: Use session variable and stored data in that.

Comment: The testCard.cshtml has information that is sorted in this page, card-1 is the template which will be rendered from what variables gets sent to, to card-1 and displays it in the <p> tags. What I want to achieve is that Page.Description goes to testCard.cshtml and retrieves the description variable from testCard.cshtml and get pushed back to the _SiteLayout.cshtml page.